# Set a welcome image instead of black screen when oppening an application

Tags: android, android-layout

When I am opening my application, I have a black screen for maybe 0.5sec. I would like to set a welcome screen.

Is there a possibility to do this automatically with a layout or I have to program this? And how

Comment: Do you mean the gap between App start until your main activity is loaded and shown?

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest set a theme:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.YourTheme" >
```

Then in your styles.xml set a windowBackground:

```
  <style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/welcome_msg</item>
</style>
```

However, this is showing for 0.5 of a second because your main Activity is taking quite a while to load! If you speeded up your app this wouldn't happen so I'd fix that issue then implements a proper splash screen.

Reference:

> The same exact trick is used in the Google Maps application that ships with the T-Mobile G1. When the application is launched, the user immediately sees the loading tiles of MapView. This is only a trick, the theme is simply using a tiled background that looks exactly like the loading tiles of MapView.

Comment: In the activity, if he sets his layout before starting the heavy loading the image will be displayed right away

Comment: In reference take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/window-bg-speed.html

Comment: I have an action that initializes a full screen OpenGL surface and all the resources (images, textures, meshes, etc). On my Optimus LG 2x it takes about 10 seconds. I've declared a layout that contains the opengGl surface (full screen) and an ImageView (containing the loading image). The action first sets the layout and then proceeds to load the openGl stuff. This makes so that the loading image is displayed immediatelly. Then when opengl stuff is loaded I set imageviwe's visibility to gone and I'm good.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) to the layout you load when your action starts. Then, once the Action finishes it's load and what not and you want to remove the ImageView you can just get it's instance and set it's visiblity to View.GONE